# Why can't i use QBuffer as output device of QAudio::start()?

Tags: qt4, qt4.7

I just copied the sample code from Qt's doc , the only difference is i choose to use memory buffer instead of a local file , so i placed a `QBuffer buffer` in `QAudio::start()` , but when `stateChanged` emitted , `buffer` was empty , and result in a `QAudio::IOError`

> Class Dummy    {
>           private:
>                 QBuffer buffer;    };

```
void Dummpy::loop()

{
    QAudioFormat format;
    // set up the format you want, eg.
    format.setFrequency(8000);
    format.setChannels(1);
    format.setSampleSize(8);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

    QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
        qWarning()<<"default format not supported try to use nearest";
        format = info.nearestFormat(format);
    }

    audio = new QAudioInput(format, this);
    connect (audio , SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)) , SLOT(stateChanged(QAudio::State)));

    QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, SLOT(stopRecording()));
    audio->start (&buffer); // was originally a QFile , i put a QBuffer here
}
```

Why is it failing ?

**EDIT**

---

Still minimal here , no error handling:

```
void Window::stateChanged(const QAudio::State &state)
{
    if ( state == QAudio::StoppedState )
    {
        buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        qDebug() << "Finished." << buffer.readAll().length();
        buffer.close();
    }
}
```

And before audio->start (&buffer) ,

`buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate);`

Comment: How are you initializing `buffer`?

Comment: @Mat , it's declared as `QBuffer buffer` in the header file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `open()` a `QIODevice` before you use it. Insert something like...

```
buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

...before...

```
audio->start (&buffer); // was originally a QFile , i put a QBuffer here
```

Comment: i tried `ReadWrite` , it's not working; but the usage of `WriteOnly` here , and re-open with `ReadOnly` , don't know why , but for now , i just want to close the question without deleting it.

Comment: `ReadWrite` should work fine, it's even included in the [documentation here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qbuffer.html#details). Would you mind updating your question with the code where you initialise your `QBuffer`?

Comment: it's a private memeber declared in the header file